# Using Asp.Net MVC RenderPartial outside of a view to get a string

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am deep in the bowels of my code base, and I need to render the contents of a partial url to a string.

Currently I am turning the relative url into a full url, then making a full web request for the content and converting it to a string.  This is considered sub-optimal for various reasons .

My current thought is to wire up the HtmlHelper class and invoke RenderPartial, but I'm having trouble wiring up a new HtmlHelper object.

Any thoughts on other ways of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [RazorEngine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/) for that, so you don't have to do web-requests. But you cannot use HtmlHelpers because they rely on HttpRequest which you don't have there.